# How can I ask, "Why did you send me this link?" in a polite way?

Tags: word-choice, politeness

The context is I told someone I'm looking for meetups in my area to network with certain people and this person sent me a link that does not seem relevant at all.  How do I ask, "Why did you send me this link?" in a polite way?

If I didn't care, I'd just ignore the link, but the reason I want to ask the question is because maybe they understand a way to use the resource in a way that I don't.  I'd be doing myself a disservice by not learning that.

Comment: "Why did you send me this link?" is perfectly polite.

Comment: +1 to @curiousdannii's comment. If you are shy about asking, you can always ask, *May I ask why you sent me this link?* But there is nothing impolite with the question in your title.

Comment: @curiousdanni - it depends on the exact culture you're in.  For me (relatively posh Brit), `bib`'s approach is the only one that feels non-aggressive.

Comment: "I'm a little confused -- what did you want me to see in this link?"

Comment: @curiousdannii I don't think it's "polite" as much as it's "not rude".  Over text, the tone could be misconstrued and they may think you're being ungrateful or dense.  And it may also be inefficient to ask this way: They may reply with, "because you told me to send you links like this".

Comment: @cloudfeet:  I agree with your assertion that it depends on the culture.  I just read bib's approach, and as an (what I assume is a pretty typical) American, that would strike me as a bit condescending and would quite likely earn you some ire.  My response would be something like:  "Why are you acting so self important?  I sent you the link because _________________, jerk."  If someone actually said the words "I was not too clear, **let me try again**" it would TOTALLY annoy me, because it feels like I'm being talked to by a grade school teacher.

Comment: As a sidenote: An email that *seems* to come from a sender you know and that contains *only* an obscure link (or just very few words auch as "Hey, look at this") is normally a tell-tale sign of spam / malware! In case you did follow the link, you better scan your computer thoroughly (or better yet, reinstall)

Comment: @Calphool Why would Bib's first one feel condescending to anyone? In fact, I feel that there is sense of humor involved in it. It doesn't, in the tiniest bit sound condescending.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> "I've taken a look at the link you sent me, but there must be something about it that I missed. What was it that you were particularly wanting to draw my attention to there?"

Answer (score 13):

A polite way to get someone to explain something is to suggest that the problem is yours:

> I seem to be a little slow today and not quite getting the connection between my question and the information you shared.

Similarly, when someone is not responding in a way that suggests they don't understand, you can say

> I was not too clear, let me try again [and then recast your original question].

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there isn't a pithy one line sentence that expresses gratitude, and asks for clarification in a polite manner without appearing to be curt or rude. That is the nature of emails. Tone is very hard to convey in words unless you resort to elaborate and seemingly long-winded phrases.

In BrEng it is the norm to first apologize and then use softening expressions such as: *Sorry to bother you*; *I was wondering if you could*; *Would you mind verb+ing*; *I hope I'm not creating a fuss*;   etc.

The first request is really an apology. You are openly blaming yourself for your  "incompetency". This type of polite request could backfire if your interlocutor feels like an idiot for not noticing the error himself (if there is any error involved). Then again, the person could simply reply with a "Oops! My bad/mistake I sent you the wrong link."

> I'm sorry, perhaps I am mistaken, but the link you kindly shared doesn't appear to be relevant for my situation. Am I'm missing something?

The second request implies that you know the link must be pertinent but you don't know where to look or how to use that information.

> Sorry for bothering you, but I wanted to thank you for the link and ask if you wouldn't mind explaining how it can be useful to me.

Comment: Gosh, we really do tie ourselves in knots, don't we? :p

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that perhaps they can use the resource in a way you don't understand. You can say

> Can you explain how this link is related to what I asked?

Comment: That sounds a little snippish to me.

Answer (score -1):

Why were you kind enough to send me this link?

Comment: That sounds like you're impugning his character. I would really wonder if I had offended someone on reading this.

Comment: @medica You would assume the sarcastic were intended would you? What a cynical age in which we live!

Comment: @WS2 Your answer already suggests the cynical view that most people wouldn't even have the tiny amount of kindness required to spend a few seconds mailing a link! But, putting that aside, I don't think this is a good approach. If I received that message, I'd think you were asking "Why were you kind to me?" not "Why did you mail me *that* link?" so you'd be likely to get an answer along the lines of "Because I'm a nice guy!" rather than something that would help you understand why the link was relevant to your situation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Would you have been happier had I said 'Why did you go to the trouble of sending me a link?'

Comment: @WS2 I think so, yes, though I'm not sure I could give a cogent reason why. On the other hand, it still seems a little less clear and no more polite than something more direct such as "I'm not sure how that page relates to the question I asked."

Comment: Character assassination hasn't been you're style that I've noticed; what makes you start now (or have I simply not noticed)? My comment was meant to be helpful. Clearly some others see it the same way. Remember tone can easily be missed in the written word unless very well crafted. Yours just doesn't fall into that category, that's all.

Comment: @medica well it's the tone I've been using all my life, and you are the first to object. Isn't the important thing to recognise that the other party has taken some trouble on your behalf, and all you are asking is why.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Whilst I realise that, in speech, a lot depends on how you say it, your suggestion actually sounds brusque and bordering on impertinent to me. Isn't the important thing to recognise that the other party has gone to some sort of trouble on your behalf.

Comment: Ha! That you know of...

Comment: @WS2 Well, rephrase for politeness to your taste. But, we well as recognizing that the other person has helped you out, it's also necessary to clearly convey that the message is "Please tell me why that link is relevant to me" not "Please tell me why you went to the trouble of mailing me a link."

Comment: @DavidRicherby But I think you need to say a little more than 'I am not sure how that page relates to my question'. You do need to convey thanks in some way. Perhaps 'Thanks for the link, but I am  not absolutely clear as to how it relates. Please could you explain.'

Answer (score -1):

Focus on why you want it. You may want to ask:

> Thank you so much, but let me know how this link may help me.